# Adhesive for a freezer

Tags: adhesive, temperature, freezer

I'm looking to mount a door sensor in my upright freezer, but have had some difficulty finding the right adhesive.

Open to recommendations for both permanent and removable.

Comment: What are you trying to sense? Door open/close? Temperature inside the door? Something else?

Comment: Most installers use double-sided foam tape.  The correct one is very strong.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - open door

Comment: How about attaching to the outside - typically painted metal rather than plastic.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - the magnets are too far apart

Answer (score 1):

A photo of where you want to mount the door sensor might help. A photo of the door sensor in question might also help.

In general I'd suggest something like a strong foam mounting tape, which will stick to most materials, conform to most surfaces, is somewhat flexible, and is somewhat removable if necessary. Silicone might be a reasonable choice for the same reasons, though possibly not as strong a bond.

But there are a lot of things that *might* work depending on what you're dealing with. Those just happen to be two that I've used most recently.

Clean the surfaces thoroughly before applying any adhesive, for best grip.

Comment: i tried the foam, doesn't stick inside the already cold freezer. Silicone is next

Comment: Not spray foam. 3M double-sided tape, on a rubbery base. It seems to stick stick to most surfaces pretty well, and conforms to irregular surfaces nicely.